# facebook like not get the required image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am creating a facebook like to put on my site. This component will read all posts from a specific page`s wall and display them.

I want to get the required image post on my wall  when any user like my page from my website.. I have multiple facebook likes on my page .. 
My problem is that when a user like any of the like button it get any image from my page and post it my wall . But i want that it get the specific image and post to my wall..

i also tried to put `og:image` But no success :-(
Any suggestions please.

Comment: og:image should've worked. Do you have an example or sample code to share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given enough code to diagnose your problems, but assuming that you've followed the open graph instructions on the Facebook Developers site - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ - It would be a good idea pass your target URL through the Facebook Debugger (formerly the URL Linter) it will help show you any errors you have regarding your open graph tagging implementation:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug